# Htaccess to web.config

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/?$ index.php?lang=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !lang=(en|el)
RewriteRule ^$ el [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^about$ el/about [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^classes$ el/classes [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^schedule$ el/schedule [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shedule/(.*)$ el/schedule/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^gallery$ el/gallery [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blog$ el/blog [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ el/blog/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^contact$ el/contact [R=301,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/blog/?([0-9-]+)$ reading.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|el)/schedule/?([0-9-]+)$ schedule-items.php?lang=$1&id=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|el)/(.*)$  $2?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I want the above rules translated in web.config for iis server. The online converters i tried didnt help.

Please help me.